# Find max per group and return another column

Tags: r, matrix, greatest-n-per-group

Given the following test matrix:

```
testMatrix <- matrix( c(1,1,2,10,20,30,300,100,200,"A","B","C"), 3, 4)

colnames(testMatrix) <- c("GroupID", "ElementID", "Value", "Name")
```

Here I want to find the max per group and then return the name of that column.
E.g. I would expect 1, A and 2, C. If there is a tie with max, the first match would be fine.
After that I would have to attach this to the matrix with a new Column "GroupName"

How can I do this?

I already have the Group, Max Value combination:

```
groupMax <- aggregate (as.numeric(testMatrix[,3]), by=list( testMatrix[,1] ), max )
```

The way I used to add columns to my matrix works like this (let's assume there is also already a matrix groupNames with GroupID, Name combinations):

```
testMatrix <- cbind ( testMatrix, groupNames[match( testMatrix[,1], groupNames[,1] ), 2] )
```

Comment: What you want isn't clear to me.  Is the last code line what you want?  I think groupNames should be groupMax.  Is there a reason you're working inside a matrix rather than a data.frame?

Comment: I want 2 things, but let's stick with my initial problem: out of my testMatrix I would like to get a resultMatrix with two columns: GroupID and Name. Where per GroupID the Name is taken where Value is max of the testMatrix. Out of this sample I'd like to have 1, A; 2, C in the end. Clear now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base solution, not as simple as Dan M's:

```
testMatrix <- data.frame(GroupID = c(1,1,2), ElementID = c(10,20,30), 
    Value=c(300,100,200), Name=c("A","B","C"))

A <- lapply(split(testMatrix, testMatrix$GroupID), function(x) {
        x[which.max(x$Value), c(1, 4)]
    }
)
do.call(rbind, A)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally managed to turn my matrix into a DF as you have it. Your function works just fine for me! When i let it run for 10k rows of my DF it's all good. But when I let it run for all of my stuff (25k rows, of which there are about 15k different groups), I get this error for A: "can not allocate Vector of size 93.4KB" and this one for do.call: "In rbind(deparse.level,...): Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)". What could I do here? Can I reserve more memory and if so, how?

Comment: btw: it seems to me that split() is the problem causing the error I get. in the meantime I rm() all objects I no longer needed and also extended memory to 2GB, but I still get this error. seems weird to me as 93.4 KB is really nothing those days...

Answer (score 7):

A `data.table` solution for time and memory efficiency and syntactic elegance

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(testMatrix)
DT[,list(Name = Name[which.max(Value)]),by = GroupID]
```

Comment: This trigged a thought. Have just raised [FR#2286 Inferred naming](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2286&group_id=240&atid=978) so it's auto named `Name` instead of `V1` to save needing `list(Name=Name[...])`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tyler said, a data.frame is easier to work with. Here's an option:

```
testMatrix <- data.frame(GroupID = c(1,1,2), ElementID = c(10,20,30), Value=c(300,100,200), Name=c("A","B","C"))
ddply(testMatrix, .(GroupID), summarize, Name=Name[which.max(Value)])
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your input! I tried to convert my matrix into a data frame and I got an error (the real one, not the test one of course, something like double row.names?). Also I don't have rights to install the plyr package. Is there no way to solve this one with basic functions?

Comment: @BaseBallBatBoy I can't say this will work for sure without looking at the error, but try setting `rownames(testMatrix) <- NULL` before converting to a data frame.

Comment: I first tried: testDF <- as.data.frame(testMatrix) , which didn't work. Now I do it like DanM said and it just worked fine: testDF <- data.frame(GroupID=testMatrix[,1], ElementID=testMatrix[,2], Value=testMatrix[,3], Name=testMatrix[,4])

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a nice way to do this via dplyr

```
filter(group_by(testMatrix,GroupID),min_rank(desc(Value))==1)
```