# Is there a way to "auto-name" expression in J

Tags: r, data.table

I have a few questions/suggestions concerning [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/).

---

```
R)  X = data.table(x=c("q","q","q","w","w","e"),y=1:6,z=10:15)
R) X[,list(sum(y)),by=list(x)]
   x V1
1: q  6
2: w  9
3: e  6
```

I think it is too bad that one has to write

```
R) X[,list(y=sum(y)),by=list(x)]
   x y
1: q 6
2: w 9
3: e 6
```

It should default to keeping the same column name (ie: y) where the function calls only one column, this would be a massive gain in most of the cases, typically in finance as we usually look as weighted sums or last time or...
=> Is there any variable I can set to default to this behaviour ?

---

When doing a selectI might want to do a calculus on few columns and apply another operation for all other columns.
I mean too bad that when I want this:

```
R)  X = data.table(x=c("q","q","q","w","w","e"),y=1:6,z=10:15,t=20:25,u=30:35)
R) X
   x y  z  t  u
1: q 1 10 20 30
2: q 2 11 21 31
3: q 3 12 22 32
4: w 4 13 23 33
5: w 5 14 24 34
6: e 6 15 25 35
R) X[,list(y=sum(y),z=last(z),t=last(t),u=last(u)),by=list(x)] #LOOOOOOOOOOONGGGG 
#EXPR
   x y  z  t  u
1: q 6 12 22 32
2: w 9 14 24 34
3: e 6 15 25 35
```

I cannot write it like...

```
R) X[,list(sum(y)),by=list(x),defaultFn=last] #defaultFn would be 
applied to all remaniing columns
```

=> Can I do this somehow (may be setting an option)?

---

Thanks

Comment: I show two expressions that I don't know how to write differently, the questions are then... it is the best it can be done ?

Comment: Did you know that data.table has a [mailing list](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/datatable-help) where you can ask development/feature request type questions?

Comment: @statquant If you edit the question title along the lines of "is there a way to auto name expressions in j?" or something like that, then it'll be a good question. Remember we're trying to build a knowledge base here that can be searched easily in future. Putting thought into the question title keeps us on side. The answer to part 2 seems like `lapply(.SD,last)`, does that work? Search for examples of that idiom; one is in `example(data.table)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On part 1, that's not a bad idea. We already do that for expressions in `by`, and something close is already on the list for `j` :

[FR#2286 Inferred naming could apply to j=colname[...]](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2286&group_id=240&atid=978)
[Find max per group and return another column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612725/403310)

But if we did do that it would probably need to be turned on via an option, to maintain backwards compatibility.  I've added a link in that FR back to this question.

---

On the 2nd part how about :

```
X[,c(y=sum(y),lapply(.SD,last)[-1]),by=x]
   x y  z  t  u
1: q 6 12 22 32
2: w 9 14 24 34
3: e 6 15 25 35
```

Please ask multiple questions separately, though. Each question on S.O. is supposed to be a single question.

Comment: Hey Matthew, I guess this is ok for this example but let's suppose you do `X[,c(y=sum(y),z=sum(z),lapply(.SD,last)[-c(1,2)]),by=x]` this can become messy again... I realize that the request is a bit clumsy but I think being able to access "all remaining" columns would be a great feature

Comment: Have you experimented with `.SDcols`?